# Foreach issue in get_posts or wp_query function

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

My category is coming from comma separated place and then i put it into wp_query's args array, but my query gives me only last category's posts. Please have a look at my code below:

````
$content_arr = explode(",", $content);

  if ( is_array($content_arr) && count($content_arr) > 0 ) {
    foreach ($content_arr as $category_name) { // Category loop
      $args = array(
        'category_name'  => trim($category_name),
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'post_date',
      );

      $output = '';      
      // $posts = get_posts($args);
      $post_counter = 1;

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
              //the_post_thumbnail();
            else: 

            endif;
            $output .= '<div class="col-md-4 mb-5">'.get_the_ID().'-'.get_the_title().'</div>';
            $post_counter++;
        endwhile; 
        $the_query->reset_postdata();
        echo $post_counter."-";
      endif;
    ```
In **$content_arr** have 3 category as array element so first foreach is running 3 times but my output is showing only one category posts.
Somehow it is resetting my previous category's results.
How can i show my all categories posts one by one?
Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing the variable `$output` outside the `foreach` loop then please define `$output= '';` outside the loop, that might be help which could reset your result and display only last loop results

** Make sure you're passing category slugs to WP_Query

Hope this could help you to trace your code

Answer (score 0):

Actually i made a logical mistake here in line number 11.
It should not initial the string, **$output = '';**
Thanks.